# User sort by role administrator area

Tags: columns

I am looking on all the internet but I can't find the answer. 
I want to add a column in the users administrator list to sort by user role. 
I don't know programming and i can't find a plugin (Admin Columns pro don't do this).
I know for sure it's a simple function to the functions.php .
If anyone can help me will be nice. This answer is not anywhere in the internet

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to `functions.php` of your current theme ( preferably, child theme ):

```
function wpse_user_sortable_columns($columns) {
    $columns['role'] = 'role';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_users_sortable_columns', 'wpse_user_sortable_columns');
```

This will change `Role` column to be sortable.

Comment: It is indeed sortable that way, but it orders by username still, not Role alphabetically as you would have expected - roles are stored as serialized array (and user can have multiple roles), so you have to create your "main role" column (or whatever) and sort that based on custom pre_get_users(). See https://wpquestions.com/WordPress_Multisite_Sorting_by_user_role_on_admin_user_table/10322